# What is the use of __iomem in linux while writing device drivers?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have seen that `__iomem` is used to store the return type of `ioremap()`, but I have used `u32` in ARM architecture for it and it works well.

So what difference does `__iomem` make here? And in which circumstances should I use it exactly?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Lots of type casts are going to just "work well". However, this is not very strict. Nothing stops you from casting a `u32` to a `u32 *` and dereference it, but this is not following the kernel API and is prone to errors.

`__iomem` is a cookie used by [Sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse), a tool used to  find possible coding faults in the kernel. If you don't compile your kernel code with Sparse enabled, `__iomem` will be ignored anyway.

Use Sparse by first installing it, and then adding `C=1` to your `make` call. For example, when building a module, use:

```
make -C $KPATH M=$PWD C=1 modules
```

---

`__iomem` is defined like this:

```c
# define __iomem        __attribute__((noderef, address_space(2)))
```

Adding (and requiring) a cookie like `__iomem` for all I/O accesses is a way to be stricter and avoid programming errors. You don't want to read/write from/to I/O memory regions with absolute addresses because you're usually using virtual memory. Thus,

```c
void __iomem *ioremap(phys_addr_t offset, unsigned long size);
```

is usually called to get the virtual address of an I/O physical address `offset`, for a specified length `size` in bytes. `ioremap()` returns a pointer with an `__iomem` cookie, so this *may now* be used with inline functions like `readl()`/`writel()` (although it's now preferable to use the more explicit macros `ioread32()`/`iowrite32()`, for example), which accept `__iomem` addresses.

Also, the `noderef` attribute is used by Sparse to make sure you don't dereference an `__iomem` pointer. Dereferencing should work on some architecture where the I/O is really memory-mapped, but other architectures use special instructions for accessing I/Os and in this case, dereferencing won't work.

Let's look at an example:

```c
void *io = ioremap(42, 4);
```

Sparse is not happy:

```
warning: incorrect type in initializer (different address spaces)
    expected void *io
    got void [noderef] <asn:2>*
```

Or:

```c
u32 __iomem* io = ioremap(42, 4);
pr_info("%x\n", *io);
```

Sparse is not happy either:

```
warning: dereference of noderef expression
```

In the last example, the first line is correct, because `ioremap()` returns its value to an `__iomem` variable. But then, we deference it, and we're not supposed to.

This makes Sparse happy:

```c
void __iomem* io = ioremap(42, 4);
pr_info("%x\n", ioread32(io));
```

Bottom line: always use `__iomem` where it's required (as a return type or as a parameter type), and use Sparse to make sure you did so. Also: do not dereference an `__iomem` pointer.

**Edit**: Here's a great [LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/102232/) about the inception of `__iomem` and functions using it.

Comment: Beautiful explanation. That's to the point with some good references.

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Very nicely explained.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Straight and  Short (S3) Explanation.
There is an article https://lwn.net/Articles/653585/ for more details.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33341799)