# Difference between void __iomem * and void* __iomem?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, gcc-warning

I am using `sparse linux tool` to clean the noise from the code. Suppose I have following struct defined in file `abc.c` as:

```
static struct check1 {
  void __iomem **base_regs;
};
```

In the same file `abc.c`. I have following line of code as well (Let X be a positive integer):

**case 1:**

```
static struct check1 *check1_var;
struct check2 {
   void* __iomem base= check1_var -->base_regs[X];
}
```

**case 2:**

```
struct check2 {
   void __iomem *base= check1_var-->base_regs[X];
}
```

In Case 1, I am getting the following warning

```
warning: incorrect type in initializer (different address spaces)
```

However, this warning get removed when i switched to case 2.

My Question is: What is the difference between `void __iomem *` and `void* __iomem`. In my view they should be the same ? Please help me out here, I am not getting why this warning get removed in case 2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100536/what-is-the-use-of-iomem-in-linux-while-writing-device-drivers

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR Thanks for sharing it here. But I have gone through this, but didn't find my answer. As you can see in `struct check1` `base_regs` is also tagged with `__iomem` and in both case i am assigning the `__iomem` tagged pointer then what is the difference. ?

Comment: @AmitSharma Read this http://lwn.net/Articles/102232/. This shows a similar discussion https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/9/24/1187.

Comment: @iqstatic Thanks.!! No explanation in there.. looking for explanation

Comment: @AmitSharma That is the way it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the link mentioned, the 2.6.9 kernel and later contains a series of changes designed to improve how the kernel works with I/O memory. The first of these is a new `__iomem` annotation used to mark pointers to I/O memory. These annotations work much like the `__user` markers, except that they reference a different address space.

The definition is as given below:

```
# define __user         __attribute__((noderef, address_space(1)))
# define __iomem        __attribute__((noderef, address_space(2)))
```

As with `__user`, the `__iomem` marker serves a documentation role in the kernel code; it is ignored by the compiler. When checking the code with sparse, however, developers will see a whole new set of warnings caused by code which mixes normal pointers with __iomem pointers, or which de-references those pointers.

`void* __iomem` and `void __iomem *` are not the same. The latter is the way it has to be done as by using `__iomem` you are providing the attribute to the `base` pointer.